# Magento 2: Facing issue with get current quote cart subtotal from RulesApplier plugin

Tags: cart, quote, magento2.3.5, subtotal

I have using **Magento\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier** Plugin. Using **aroundApplyRules** method need to get current cart subtotal. I have need customisation to validate condition for cart subtotal with cart price rule subtotal. But getting every time previous quote subtotal.

When add to cart product first time then getting subtotal 0 after second time add to cart product then getting previous cart subtotal. But not getting every time current cart total.

**etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier">
        <plugin name="curent_cart_subtotal_collection"
                type="Custom\Module\Plugin\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

**Plugin/RulesApplier.php**

```
public function aroundApplyRules( 
    SalesRulesApplier $subject,
    Closure          $proceed,
    $item,
    $rules,
    $skipValidation,
    $couponCode
) {

 public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session  $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->cart            = $cart;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }


    $subTotal = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
   // $subTotal = $this->cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal();

    return $proceed($item, $rules, $skipValidation, $couponCode);

}
```

Comment: if you have an around plugin and you don't execute the original method first, you won't get the new subtotal. try calling `$proceed(...)` first and see what happens

Comment: @Marius yes I am calling $proceed(...) method  
return $proceed($item, $rules, $skipValidation, $couponCode);
 I have updated in code.

Comment: not sure what the problem is here...you say you get the subtotal before the rules are applies? this is normal behavior, I think. You first get the subtotal and then you apply the original method. it's normal to get a wrong sutotal initially

Comment: First time add to cart product subtotal is getting 0. I need subtotal every time when product add to cart with correct subtotal. I have updated details, Please read my question again.